# How to debug an issue that occurs only after eas build?

Tags: android, react-native, expo, google-play-console, eas

I have tested an Expo based React Native app on my phone using the Expo app and it works fine. After building the app for Android (creating the AAB file), I deployed it to the Play Console for testing and see the following error:

```
Stack trace
global@1:59664
FATAL EXCEPTION: mqt_native_modules
Process: com.soulspark.testpublishapptwo, PID: 3645
com.facebook.react.common.JavascriptException: TypeError: undefined is not a function, js engine: hermes, stack:
anonymous@1:951728
loadModuleImplementation@1:60903
guardedLoadModule@1:60452
metroRequire@1:60080
anonymous@1:805090
loadModuleImplementation@1:60903
guardedLoadModule@1:60452
metroRequire@1:60080
anonymous@1:801528
loadModuleImplementation@1:60903
guardedLoadModule@1:60452
metroRequire@1:60080
anonymous@1:644682
loadModuleImplementation@1:60903
guardedLoadModule@1:60452
metroRequire@1:60080
anonymous@1:644329
loadModuleImplementation@1:60903
guardedLoadModule@1:60452
metroRequire@1:60080
anonymous@1:67303
loadModuleImplementation@1:60903
guardedLoadModule@1:60452
metroRequire@1:60080
anonymous@1:67210
loadModuleImplementation@1:60903
guardedLoadModule@1:60409
metroRequire@1:60080
global@1:59664
    at com.facebook.react.modules.core.ExceptionsManagerModule.reportException(ExceptionsManagerModule.java:72)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.facebook.react.bridge.JavaMethodWrapper.invoke(JavaMethodWrapper.java:372)
    at com.facebook.react.bridge.JavaModuleWrapper.invoke(JavaModuleWrapper.java:188)
    at com.facebook.jni.NativeRunnable.run(Native Method)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadHandler.dispatchMessage(MessageQueueThreadHandler.java:27)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
    at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadImpl$4.run(MessageQueueThreadImpl.java:228)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:923)
```

How do I debug this error? I'm not sure where to start because I don't know which code line the error corresponds to.

I have tried to:

1. Disable hermes
2. Add the "debugSymbolLevel" property in order to get better errors

Do let me know if there's any other information I should add here.

Comment: this guide provides advice on how to debug issues: https://docs.expo.dev/build-reference/troubleshooting/